# Is the monthly loan fee non-refundable when a loan contract is terminated?

Tags: football-manager-2013

I just had the following face-palm moment: found out that a very interesting player was listed for loan, quickly moved in with loan offer, the salary wasn't much so I "snatched" him up. A little while later I noticed that my transfer budget is decreased pretty significantly, so I checked my transfer history to see what I spent the money on.

Turns out the contract had a £300K/mo fee which I have not paid attention to. Figured I don't need the player for such a cost, and that I had better use of that £3.6M. I terminated the loan next day (in-game), but my budget has not increased. The transfer expenditure is consistent with my calculation, i.e. players I bought + £300K * 12.

What makes sense is that my team is charged for the month, but the remaining 11 months transfer budget is returned. However it doesn't seem to be the case here. Does anybody know if this is a permanent situation, or until the next month?